# iOS Releasing object too early - possible confusion with Autorelease and Copy

Tags: objective-c, ios, copy, autorelease

I've written an app with a custom Search class in it. This builds up an array of results.

I then assign that array into my FirstViewController class, and reload a table view which has the results array assigned to it

```
self.aResults = [thisSearch.aResults copy]
...
[[self searchResults] reloadData];
```

Shortly after doing that I'm releasing **thisSearch**

```
[thisSearch release];
```

This all works fine, and shows the the results table, but if I scroll down the table and look at the rows below they are all blank, then as I scroll back up the app crashes when it reloads the recycled table cells.

This wasn't happening to me before, but I realised I was leaking memory, so I went **autorelease** crazy, and added lots of **autorelease** to my *Search* class. But not my *FirstViewController* class.

So if I use **Copy**, does it not actually make a copy of the object, does it just increase the reference counter? So when I destroy *Search*, am I destroying the results array in there, and therefore destroying what the FirstViewController is trying to access for the table view?

Sorry if that doesn't make much sense, I'm not feeling very with it today.

Comment: Instead of `self.aResults = [thisSearch.aResults copy]` you should make aResults copy-ed property like `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *aResults;`. Then when you set this property, it will automatically get a copy of object you are setting it to. When done with whatever is inside aResults, do `self.aResults = nil` and it will be released. I haven't submitted this as answer as it's just a tip, but it's not a reason why your app crashes. And without more code, I don't know why it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `copy` objects (and to do so that object must conform to the `NSCopying` Protocol but that's the case of `NSArray`) it is exactly as if you were `init`ializing it for the first time with predifined values.

So it is your responsability to `release` objects that have been `copied`.

Thefore you must do :

```
self.aResults = [thisSearch.aResults copy]
...

[thisSearch release]; // When you release thisSearch this will not affect aResults
...

// then you can either do:
[self.aResults autorelease]; // but then do not release it later on
// or
[self.aResults release]; // when you're done with it
```

However I doubt this will solve you memory issues. By over autoreleasing (and still releasing things) you might have completely corrupted your application memory management.

To try to fix it, try to analyze your project and see what comes up.

[image]

Also I attach the [Apple Memory Management link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) that one should read monthly until it becomes second nature.

Comment: Aaaah I should have run Analyze! I ran that, and it pointed me to an NSDicitonary which I was autoreleasing, and told me the reference counter was already 0, because I was assigning that dictionary to an array which was also autorelease - so I suppose it was trying to release that dicitonary when the array it was in was already gone